# Call to a member function set() on a non-object error looping through array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Working in CI 2.1.0 and getting  a "Call to a member function set() on a non-object..." error with the code excerpt looping through the array below. Seemingly it's an array of all strings so I'm having trouble seeing why it seems to fail in the middle.

Any insights as to what's going on would be great. Researched other questions on this error, but still at a loss.

```
Code excerpt:
foreach($data['jobs'] as $job)
{
foreach($job as $key=>$value){
  $job->set($key,$value);

}

}
```

$data['jobs'] array:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [job_id] => 149 [company] => Minnesota Life Insurance [location] => Barrington, IL [start_date] => March '98 [end_date] => June '98 [description] =>
Primary responsibility was research and design of sales and training presentations.
Responsible for scheduling a three person sales and training staff.
[title] => Administrative Secretary [resume_id] => 96 [order_id] => 0 [profile_id] => 38 [user_id] => 1 [vanity_name] => Sample of Template 3 [template_id] => 3 [date_add] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [date_mod] => 2012-03-04 11:00:05 ) [1] => Array ( [job_id] => 150 [company] => Manpower Temporary Services [location] => Naperville, IL [start_date] => Dec' 04 [end_date] => June '98 [description] =>
Assigned to GE Silicones in the industrial sales division.
Responsible for analysis of monthly, weekly, and, daily sales reports.
Responsible for scheduling training classes, seminars, and conferences
[title] => Independent Contractor [resume_id] => 96 [order_id] => 1 [profile_id] => 38 [user_id] => 1 [vanity_name] => Sample of Template 3 [template_id] => 3 [date_add] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [date_mod] => 2012-03-04 11:00:05 ) [2] => Array ( [job_id] => 151 [company] => KSMR Radio 92.5/94.3FM [location] => Winona, MN [start_date] => May '96 [end_date] => May '97 [description] =>
In charge of a 36 member staff, as well as a 7 member management team, with duties that include disciplinary actions, budgeting, special requests, program scheduling, and hiring.
Balancing a $15,000 dollar budget, as well as chairing a committee to receive a grant for increasing station amenities such as wattage, equipment, space, and music library.
[title] => General Manager [resume_id] => 96 [order_id] => 2 [profile_id] => 38 [user_id] => 1 [vanity_name] => Sample of Template 3 [template_id] => 3 [date_add] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [date_mod] => 2012-03-04 11:00:05 ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $job isn't a class, thats why your getting the 'call to a member function set() on a **non-object**' - $job is an array. You have to access it like the following.

```
 $job['job_id'] = 149;
 $job['company'] = 'Minnesota Life Insurance';
```

Maybe you want to transfer the values of $job into a class?

Comment: Thanks -- I believe I follow. What still doesn't make sense is elsewhere when I use a simple array like $data['resume'] and I pass it using foreach that works just fine.

Comment: @jsuissa It could be that the elements for $data['resume'], are classes themselves, but the elements for $data['jobs'] are just simple types.

Comment: $job-> should have been $jobs->. Thx! Once you said it isn't a class it just clicked that it must be a typo.

Comment: @jsuissa - hehe it happens :) Best of luck to you